# Custom views of smart pointer objects in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I need to use smart pointers for an application which has several hierarchy of classes. One difficulty while debug the code is the view of smart pointers (e.g. `unique_ptr`) inside the watch windows of Visual Studio 2015. It always shows `[ptr]`, `[deleter]` and `[Raw View]`at the same time, while I mostly care about seeing quickly the content of `[ptr]` when expanding the view for the pointer. Is there a way to make debugging easier and customize the view of displaying the content of smart pointer to become same as raw pointers in visual Studio 2015? I know that this should be doable by using the appropriate NavisFile, however I don't know how should the following NavisFile  be modified to show the content of `[ptr]` ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010"> 

  <Type Name="std::unique_ptr&lt;*&gt;">
      <SmartPointer Usage="Minimal">_Mypair._Myval2</SmartPointer>
      <DisplayString Condition="_Mypair._Myval2 == 0">empty</DisplayString>
      <DisplayString Condition="_Mypair._Myval2 != 0">unique_ptr {*_Mypair._Myval2}</DisplayString>
      <Expand>
          <Item Condition="_Mypair._Myval2 != 0" Name="[ptr]">_Mypair._Myval2</Item>
      </Expand>
  </Type>


</AutoVisualizer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no expert, but it seems like you could simply remove the `<Expand>` node, and then change the second `<DisplayString>` to display just `_Mypair._Myval2`, eg:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010"> 

  <Type Name="std::unique_ptr&lt;*&gt;">
      <SmartPointer Usage="Minimal">_Mypair._Myval2</SmartPointer>
      <DisplayString Condition="_Mypair._Myval2 == 0">empty</DisplayString>
      <DisplayString Condition="_Mypair._Myval2 != 0">_Mypair._Myval2</DisplayString>
  </Type>


</AutoVisualizer>
```

Comment: Yes this works as you said. Many thanks for your answer.